# Getting an e-mail to popup on one monitor, with a message box appearing on another

Tags: excel, multiple-monitors, vba

So I'm creating an e-mail scrape. Scrapes, etc. etc.

It tries to detect if a given vendor name is in the e-mail. If it finds it, great! It knows who it came from.

However, sometimes it'll fail to find a name. What I'm currently doing is displaying the e-mail in question, and popping up an input box asking "Who is this e-mail from?"

Unfortunately, the e-mail and the input box tend to pop up in the same monitor, so the message box ends up "overwriting"  the e-mail, effectively hiding it. That makes it fairly difficult for the end user to see what e-mail I'm talking about!

Is there an easy way to say in VBA "Please display on whatever monitor Excel isn't using", or should I simply add into the instructions "Hey, have your outlook and Excel in different monitors for ease of use"?

Comment: and you say, users can't move the inputbox?

Answer (score 0):

A `MsgBox` doesn't include any way to specify a location. Instead, Excel displays the message box centered on the screen. If you need the capability to position the box, then the easiest solution is to rely upon the `InputBox`. Unlike `MsgBox`, `InputBox` includes option parameters for specifying a location. Here's an example:

```
vendorName = InputBox(Prompt:="Who is this e-mail from?", XPos:=2880, YPos:=1440)
```

The look and feel wont be the same with an `InputBox`, but you will be able to locate your box in (for example) the screen bottom left/right corner.

You can tell your users to input the Vendor's name, so you will know if it was found or not.

Comment: It's not the inputbox that I need to specify the location of as much as the e-mail.

Comment: @Selkie But the email is not in Excel, or is it ?

Comment: The E-mail is from outlook. A macro on Excel's side is scraping it.

Comment: @Selkie so you present it's text inside an Excel sheet and on-top position the `MsgBox` ?

Comment: @Selkie per your comments, I've wrote a second answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a `UserForm` to display your message - instead of a `MsgBox`

`UserForm`has a property named `StartUpPosition`. By default, this property is set to 1 (`CenterOwner`), which means that it should appear in the center of Excel's window.

**But**, if you have a dual-monitor system. The `UserForm` is not centered in the Excel window - On my system, `UserForm` always display on the left side of the secondary monitor, even if Excel is maximized on the primary monitor.

Try it, and even if it will be centered above the Excel window, you can easily modify it's location.

The code below will force an Excel `UserForm` to be centered in Excel's window - modify it per your needs (but try first initiating a `UserForm` without any modification - it might just pop-up on the secondary screen exactly like you need).

```
With UserForm1
  .StartUpPosition = 0
  .Left = Application.Left + (0.5 * Application.Width) - (0.5 * .Width)
  .Top = Application.Top + (0.5 * Application.Height) - (0.5 * .Height)
  .Show
End With
```